# Access entry in NetworkX matrix

Tags: python, networkx

I created a graph using a dataframe df:

```
d = {'node1': ['A','B','C','D','E'], 'node2': ['E','C','B','A','F'],'distance': [3,4,2,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

G = nx.Graph()

for i, elrow in df.iterrows():
    G.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict())
```

Then I calculate the minimum unweighted distance between all pairs:

```
sp = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)
spl = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G)
```

However, when I try to output the distance between two nodes using:

```
sp["A"]["E"]
spl["A"]["E"]
```

I get an error message:

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

I do see there are posts regarding such error, but they are more in general. Since we already have a matrix in this case, I wonder is there a more straightforward way to access the entries?

Comment: Not sure whether this is correct, but looks like it gives me what I want. I first save the generator in a dictionary and then access each entry: `sp_m = dict(sp)` and `sp_m['A']['E']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should check your networkx-version. I already realized a change with regards to return type of functions between Version 1.1 and 2.0 from `dict`s to generators.

Example for `nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length`:

- [Version 1.1, return type dict](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length.html)
- [Version 2.0, return type generator](https://pelegm-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length.html)

Try first to print out the content of the generator by

```
print(*sp)         # or
print(list(spl))
```

then you'll probably see how you can proceed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inspiration! It's really weird that `dict(sp)['A']` works but if I execute `dict(sp)['B']` right after it, there is error. The error can be fixed if I run `sp = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)` each time before accessing `dict(sp)['X']`. Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Yes, this is the nature of generators: they are not like lists or arrays, which are completely created and reside in memory until the end of the program (or any other deletion- or garbage-collection concept). They are more like _definitions_ of how to calculate all the elements they _are able to_ provide. As soon as a `next` function is applied to a generator, it returns the first element (it's called _yield_ ing). With a second `next`, it yields the second one, while the first is completely gone, like 'forgotten', no chance to access it anymore - except you create the generator once again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! This makes a lot of sense. I managed to save the generators as a dictionary, in order to avoid creating it every time. Looks like it's working, and hopefully I didn't make any unknown mistakes this way...

Comment: Oh this is the code, which is also posted as a comment to my question: `sp_m = dict(sp)` and `sp_m['A']['E']`

Comment: No, I don't think so, this is ok. Consider reading https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators for further understanding, note it's still about Python2.x, but for the general concept it's still applying.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you so much for the confirmation and reference, SpghttCd!